# can we manage badge count using azure notification hub (from panel to bulk devices)

Tags: azure, notifications, badge

I am using node in backend, and using notification hub to send bulk notification to bulk of users, is there a way to manage badge count?for both android and ios devices

Answer (score 0):

Azure Notification Hubs does not offer a feature that enables you to manage badge count. You can track the badge count on your backend and send the count with the notification (as a property of the notification request).